# Postgres download on unbuntu - Error when connecting through the application

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin

I have just downloaded postgres and set everything up as per installation guide. I can connect to the db on the command prompt without any errors. When I use the pgadmin application I get many errors when clicking into any databases(the standard and any new ones created)

I have screenshots below. Could someone point me in the right direction. I have completely uninstalled postgres several times and has not fixed the problem.

[image: Error 1]

[image: Error 2]

In case you cant access image:
10:03:06:Error:Error rel.relhasoid does not exist
10:05:05: Error: column "prosiagg" doe not exist

I get a few more errors along those lines.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pgAdmin 3 is not compatible with current Postgres versions. You will need to use pgAdmin 4

Comment: Thank you very simple should have realised that.